# Looping insert from unknown/dynamic jQuery ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm a bit stuck on this one and hope anyone can help

I have a situation where a user can create a survey and add questions to it, the answers to which are binary - if the answer is no a textbox kicks in asking why.

the form then gets fired with ajax/jQuery:

```
var formdata = $("form").serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "api.php",
    data: formdata,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        //      
    }
});
```

Other end I have it picked up now, the url delivers something along the lines of:

person=me   ///person filling out the form
&surveyID=218   ///the survey they are taking

&questionname=561  ///looped questions that the owner of the survey set
&561=0 /// from the radio button answer - yes/no
&reason1=reason+for+first //// if the answer is no, give a reason

&questionname=562
&562=1
 
&reason2=

&questionname=563
&563=1
&reason3=

So in PHP up i've tried loads of things, the most successful being

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $name => $val) {
    $array = array();
    parse_str($_REQUEST, $array);
 mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO answers (surveyID, person, questionname ) 
    VALUES ('$surveyID', '$person', '$questionname')") ; 
}
```

With a view to then looping through the answers and updating where the question id matches? I know I'm miles off with this though.

I need to insert each answer into the database against the survey and question like this

surveyID(surveyID) | question_id(questionname) | Answer(the 1 or 0 value from the question 561 562 or 563 ) | Reason(reason1 2 or 3)

so this would insert 3 new records. It's feeding through fine, but I'm really puzzled how to get the person and survey first and then loop through the questions.

If I've explained my issue badly, apologies and happy to edit and elaborate.

Comment: in your example you r just alerting the result, can you put the code you wrote to write to the database?

Comment: sorry I should've removed the alert, it's irrelevant and was just a point where I wanted to see data. will update thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are making a call to a php file using a form posting via Ajax

As you have not given an example of your form form I created what I believed to be a working example of your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3listone/8hp7cxuj/).

```
<form id="survery">

  <label for="q561">This is a question for 561:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q561" value="1"> Yes
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="q561" value="0"> No
  <br>
  <div class="reason">
    <label for="r561">Please give a reason:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="r561" value="">
  </div>
  <br>

  <input type="hidden" name="surveyID" value="218">
  <input type="hidden" name="person" value="me">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

As you can tell from the demo I have tweaked a few things so that you no longer pass duplicated & unnecessary data and added an q or r in front of the question or reason id to help with identification when looping thought the results.

As for the PHP script the `api.php` file why not something like this:

```
$questions = array();
$surveyID = $_GET['surveyID'];
$person = $_GET['person'];
$formData = $_GET;

// loop though all the form data
foreach ($formData as $key => $value) {
   // check if the first letter of key is equal to 'q'
   if(substr($key, 0, 1) === 'q'){

      // clean the key to just get the id
      $qId = str_replace('q','',$key);

      // check to see if the _GET has been set otherwise use empty string
      $reason = isset($_GET['r'.$qId]) ? $_GET['r'.$qId] : '';

      // add this question to the array
      // with answer and reason
      $questions[$qID]['answer'] = $value;
      $questions[$qID]['reason'] = $reason;
   }
}

// lastly now we have an array of just questions / answers and reasons we can loop thought it all
foreach ($questions as $key => $value) {

   // get all the variables from the questions array
   $qId = $key;
   $answer = $value['answer'];
   $reason = $value['reason'];

   // push the qId, answer & reason into the database - not sure how you do this as you only used the following in you example.
   // NOTE: THIS IS NOT SAFE AS NONE OF YOUR DATA HAS BEEN SANITIZED 
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (surveyID, person, questionname ) 
        VALUES ($surveyID, $person, $qId)") ; 
}
```

I believe the above should give you a better understanding of how to complete the task you are trying to achieve, but **please note** this is not a complete and working version of your code it is missing sanitisation as well as some extra checking to prevent errors.

Please look at [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) as the `mysql_query` method is deprecated.